# Cannot see updates in Chrome after AngularJS added data uing ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am successfully getting JSON responce. Chrome developer tools shows there are added new `option` elements but I cannot see them in drop-down (in `select`) in Chrome. Do  ineed to call extra function to update `select`? How to fix it?
**HTML**

```
<div class="controls" ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="span4"  name="product_property" id="product_properties" ng-repeat="property in properties">
        <option value="{{property.name}}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http){
    $http.get(HOST + "/getProductProperties")
            .success(
            function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.properties = data;

            })
};
```

Comment: You should probably replace ng-repeat with ng-options... Are yo sure it is getting into success handler and data is what you expect it is?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select ngOptions

Comment: Data received as expected. `$scope.properties = data;` is entered. New options is in html but hidden from Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: What do you mean by `New options is in html` ?

Comment: Chrome developer tools shows there are added new `option` elements into html of the page

Comment: Resolved. I should have updated resources on tomcat ;) @chriskelly, thanks for resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here
http://plnkr.co/edit/jbT5Yjt8Lv3NvWFvGhYH?p=preview

```
<select class="span4"  name="product_property" id="product_properties">
        <option value="{{property.name}}"  ng-repeat="property in properties">{{property.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

1. `ng-repeat` should be inside option tag
2. Your display value for option is empty